# Reading variables from other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I know there are many posts on this topic, but I just can't figure out how to implement the answers.

```
def name():
  name = (input('enter name'))

def age():  
  age = (input('enter age'))

def username(name,age):
  username = (name+age)
  print (username)

name()
age()
username(name,age)
```

what do i need to do to make this work. From other posts i think i have to put the variable in brackets on the function name line, but this seems not to be working, with the error:

Comment: You're looking for the `global` keyword, but this is generally bad practice. Consider returning from the functions instead

Answer (score 1):

Your functions should return a value if you want to store them in a variable. Update your functions to return a string and assign this to a variable, you can then pass this variable to your other functions as a parameter

```
def get_name():
    return input('Enter name: ')

def get_age():  
    return input('Enter age: ')

def get_username(name, age):
    return '{0}_{1}'.format(name, age)

name = get_name()
age = get_age()
username = get_username(name, age)

print(username)

>> Enter name: 
>  Alan
>> Enter age: 
>  20
>> Alan_20
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing :You must return from function if you want to use the result of any function.

Second : you don't need to call each function you are already calling both function in third function :

so try this :

```
def name():
  name = (input('enter name'))
  return name

def age():
  age = (input('enter age'))
  return age

def username(name,age):


    username=(name()+age())
    print(username)


username(name,age)
```